# objective-c how to save variable name and value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

I have five integers.I added all integers to a mutableArray and shuffled it.

```
int A = 1;
int B = 2;
int C = 3;
int D = 4;
int E = 5;

myArray = [2,1,3,5,4]; //shuffled array
```

is it possible to get variable names of each integer in the array?
please help me.

Comment: Rather to use only array just use array-->dictionary for your purpose. I mean set the dictionary for each variable having its value and variable name that can give you name as well as value when you want it.

Comment: Please Accept my answer if it is useful to you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case NSDictionary would be feasible, you can store both the Variable Names and their Values:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"A",@"2",@"B",@"3",@"C",@"4",@"D",@"5",@"E", nil];
```

Now you can fetch all the keys of the dictionary like:

```
NSArray *arr = [dict allKeys];      // which will be [A,B,C,D,E]
```

And you can fetch the values for those keys like:

```
for (int i=0; i<arr.count; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[dict valueForKey:[arr objectAtIndex:i]]);  // Will print 1,2,3,4,5
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to do that (and keep track of where each variable is put after the shuffling (that's what you want to do, right?)), I would create an NSDictionary for each entry and then shuffle it...

```
int aInt = 1;
int bInt = 2;
int cInt = 3;
int dInt = 4;
int eInt = 5;

NSDictionary* a = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:aInt],@"value",
                                                "A",@"name"];

NSDictionary* b = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:bInt],@"value",
                                                "B",@"name"];

NSDictionary* c = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:cInt],@"value",
                                                "C",@"name"];

NSDictionary* d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:dInt],@"value",
                                                "D",@"name"];

NSDictionary* e = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:eInt],@"value",
                                                "e",@"name"];

NSMutableArray* myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:a,b,c,d,e,nil];

// Then... you may shuffle it...
```

Answer (score -1):

A more... elegant solution (not with 5 different variables... but with int variables stored in an array)

**Code :**

```
int num[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    NSDictionary* dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:num[i]],@"value",
                                                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:i],@"id",
                     nil];

    [arr addObject:dic];
}

NSLog(@"arr : %@",arr);
```

**Output :**

```
arr : (
        {
        id = 0;
        value = 1;
    },
        {
        id = 1;
        value = 2;
    },
        {
        id = 2;
        value = 3;
    },
        {
        id = 3;
        value = 4;
    },
        {
        id = 4;
        value = 5;
    },
        {
        id = 5;
        value = 6;
    },
        {
        id = 6;
        value = 7;
    },
        {
        id = 7;
        value = 8;
    },
        {
        id = 8;
        value = 9;
    },
        {
        id = 9;
        value = 10;
    }
)
```